# Showing fragments from push notifications

Tags: android-intent, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-fragmentactivity

I am using push notifications to display fragments in my app but my implementation seems unstable

There are two scenarios when the app is running and when the app isn't running

In both scenarios I want the app display a particular fragment

Here is my FragmentActivity in  my Manifest file

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NoBackground"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
```

Here is my code to create the notification, which is called by the service when it receives a GCM message

```
private void sendNotification(String message) {

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            getApplicationContext(), requestID, new Intent(
                    getApplicationContext(), Main.class).setAction(Actions.SHOW_FRIENDS_FRAGMENT), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSound(
                    RingtoneManager
                            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(Util.getApp().getNotificationId(), mBuilder.build());
}
```

An in my activity I check in both onCreate and onNewIntent

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    checkIntent(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    checkIntent(intent);
}

private void checkIntent(Intent i){
    try{
        String action = i.getAction();

        if(action != null){
            if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(Actions.SHOW_FRIENDS_FRAGMENT)){
                showFriendsFragment();
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

The problem is if the action is found in onCreate when the app is restarted the action is still there so it will always start on that page. 
The behaviour doesn't occur when the action is found in onNewIntent but this is only called while the app is running.

I have tried using extras and removing them after showing the fragment, changing the pending intent flag to `CANCEL_CURRENT`, `ONE_SHOT` but the behaviour is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after days of trying to figure this out. I have been unable to find any conventional method to solve this so I've used a hack.

1. In your Main Activity define a `public static boolean checkIntent = false`
2. Create a Dummy Activity which is called when you click on the notification so

   ```
   final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
       getApplicationContext(), requestID, new Intent(
               getApplicationContext(), DummyActivity.class).putExtra("data", data), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   ```
3. in DummyActivity

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   Intent i = getIntent();
   if (i != null) {
       String data = i.getStringExtra("data");
       Main.checkIntent = true;
       startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Main.class).putExtra(
               "data", data));
   }
   finish();
   }
   ```
4. Finally in the checkIntent method

   ```
   private void checkIntent(Intent i){
   try{
   String data = i.getStringExtra("data");

   if(data!= null){
       checkIntent = false;
       showFriendsFragment();
   }
   }catch(Exception e){

   }
   }
   ```

Comment: i think should be better way. this is not a good way to resolve it